# can i check an image size before resizing it in less?

Tags: css, image, less

I'd like to write some Less that will check check an image's width/height before applying a percentage scaling.

The idea is that I'll have a fixed size div and I'll want to center a set of images in that div and re-size them to be as big as possible without getting cut off or accidentally resizing the div. The source images will be varying sizes and even varying W/H ratios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply in CSS

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

You images will fill the div (if they are wider than the DIV), but never break it